# Initializing a variable with a dynamic body

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a very specific case, when based on length_type attribute the body of type is different (as shown in example).

```
    enum LengthTypeEnum {
      SELECT = 'SELECT',
      STATIC = 'STATIC',
      CONDITION = 'CONDITION',
      PERIOD = 'PERIOD'
    }

  type LengthType<T extends LengthTypeEnum> =
    T extends LengthTypeEnum.SELECT ? { length_type: T, lengths: number[] } :
    T extends LengthTypeEnum.PERIOD ?  { length_type: T, length_min: number; length_max: number }:
    T extends LengthTypeEnum.STATIC ? { length_type: T, length: number }:
    T extends LengthTypeEnum.CONDITION ? { length_type: T, conditions: any[] }:
    {}
  ;

  let variableLength: LengthType<LengthTypeEnum> | null = null

  function handleSelect(length_type: LengthTypeEnum):void{
    variableLength = initializeLengthData(length_type)
  }

  function initializeLengthData<T extends LengthTypeEnum>(length_type: T):LengthType<T>{
    if(length_type === LengthTypeEnum.SELECT){
      return {length_type: length_type, lengths: []} as any as LengthType<T>
    }else if(length_type === LengthTypeEnum.PERIOD){
      return {length_type: length_type, length_min:0, length_max: 0} as any as LengthType<T>
    }else if(length_type === LengthTypeEnum.STATIC){
      return {length_type: length_type,length: 0} as any as LengthType<T>
    }else if(length_type === LengthTypeEnum.CONDITION){
      return {length_type: length_type,conditions: []} as any as LengthType<T>
    }
    return {} as LengthType<T> ;
  }
```

Type "Length Type" works itself just fine. So once i`m checking the length type value the compiler knows what the rest body of variable will be.

However i have a problem with initializing a variable, when the length_type will be chosen. The code works but it uses awfully looking as any type casting. Is it possible to make it without as any. Or should i use another approach?

Minimal rep. version in [GUI example playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Minimal rep. version in [Typescript only playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4UwOwVwW2AZSBzALgCwCoE8AOYCi0cA3gFCigDK%208%20AwhsALzADk1tDrANORcJQwBBDAEk6zNoJHiefCnQDyAOQAiosSsmslajaJVz%20wAAr4ASgdXazlxatbzgAX1J8UuMAmTpseADyMYAAeKJAAJgDO3hComJ6EsAB8zE5BoRHRiLG%20CUQAdBz0jAD8wMTAADY%20aAD6HngAXMAY3FU1kc1EAEZgAE4A2gC6LsCNaeAZEFExcX4EBbZWwGXl7Tl1DWDNretxtTAAlhBdsL19ANx76AcAhsGnMOcu4xTpYdNZNfOJMIXCYgkZQq1Q29U8OzaoLij2ezleoHemVmuTwv3yunUmmUKzW0JuW0hwAAxgB7aaHFCHcmdYC3CBYYYvJzEVwgC5uEDVFDAAButz6h1u3Wq2RhKPiATFqIWyWAAB9gNBKpVJMrKpzgAAzKAQYlU8nAND08LVShgar6gAU%20M2EIlPyIAEpGrzSYdwmQKPzBcLRTVJMdKULKocAF5gaVoVS3FC3G01cF4J18Vx8HV6g0QYBBqm3UMRqMxuOBSYfGZRx3JBNgwktF2VzyBJJe0CHLU1-ZbZhMFiNtEFIoMJ2tih9MAoKB9bPEW1J7bXO14KEdZrDZx06L0rCbh1NjBJJzOC2RLztzsEzw9vvfPKwfJLewjpwgceT6flOd1r%20eFdgo4nAADH%20%20wwPczSARutxbgyu79mAzZHieZ4dj%20eDXnuA73tIgLPsYb5TjOaELsR3C2hBUEwTu0GYQhB5IZUp45qhibdr2N4bFWfyYvoKh4fwBEfrOrH2qRZIUlmtLrru25wbeAT0RQbKgIJM6UbRzbAByIDOEAA)

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can just copy and paste into our own IDEs and get to work on it.  Any private or third party types or values should be replaced with the simplest thing which demonstrates the issue.  Otherwise someone trying to test their suggestion will need to spend time just getting to the place where you already are.

Comment: Added both visual example and typescript only playgrounds

Comment: I am not sure if I really understood the question, but I did this. It uses union types instead of generics. It is cool for completion and stuff, but it may not fit your needs.

Comment: sigh url too long

Comment: There https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-qrffqt?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

Comment: Please put the example code here as plaintext. A link is nice but it's not enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: To use generics and get compiler-assisted type safety you have to refactor to a particular form, where you use *indexed accesses* only.  [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKX98w) shows how I'd approach it given your example. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer (after you put the example code as plaintext in the question). If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of TypeScript 5.3, the compiler really can't do [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) that affects [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters. This means that when you check, for example, `length_type === LengthTypeEnum.SELECT` inside your `initializeLengthData()` function body, it can narrow the type of `length_type` from `T` to `T & LengthTypeEnum.SELECT`, but it does absolutely nothing to `T` itself. So then you try to return `{length_type: length_type, lengths: []}` but the compiler can't confirm that as a valid `LengthType<T>`, since `LengthType<T>` is a generic [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and that cannot be evaluated without knowing what `T` is.

There are multiple open feature requests about this, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). It looks like we might see some progress on that in the near future (it's mentioned in the TS5.5 iteration plan at [microsoft/TypeScript#57475](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57475)) but for now you have to work around it.

---

Right now if you want to do something generic with multiple cases, the only support TypeScript has is to represent it in terms of an [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with a generic key.  If you can rewrite things so that you are returning a value of type `SomeInterface[K]` for generic `K`, and you can provide a value `s` of type `SomeInterface` and a key `k` of type `K`, then returning `s[k]` will be accepted.

It might seem like you can't easily do that, but one trick is to use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to make an object whose properties don't get evaluated until you index into it.  What I mean is, instead of `if (k === "a") { return f(); } else if (k === "b") { return g(); } ⋯` you write `return ({ get a() { return f(); }, get b() { return g(); ⋯ }})[k]`. That gives the same results but the latter looks like "index into this object" instead of "check lots of cases".

For your example I'd write it like this:

```
interface LengthTypeValue {
  [LengthTypeEnum.SELECT]: { lengths: number[] };
  [LengthTypeEnum.STATIC]: { length: number };
  [LengthTypeEnum.CONDITION]: { conditions: any[] };
  [LengthTypeEnum.PERIOD]: { length_min: number; length_max: number };
}

type LengthType<K extends LengthTypeEnum> =
  { [P in K]: { length_type: P } & LengthTypeValue[P] }[K];

function initializeLengthData<T extends LengthTypeEnum>(length_type: T): LengthType<T> {
  const l: LengthTypeValue = {
    get [LengthTypeEnum.SELECT]() {
      return { lengths: [] }
    },
    get [LengthTypeEnum.PERIOD]() {
      return { length_min: 0, length_max: 0 }
    },
    get [LengthTypeEnum.STATIC]() {
      return { length: 0 }
    },
    get [LengthTypeEnum.CONDITION]() {
      return { conditions: [] }
    }
  }
  return { length_type, ...l[length_type] };
}
```

So I've made a new type called `LengthTypeValue` which is a mapping from your `LengthTypeEnum` to the parts of `LengthType<>` that differ, and made a value `l` of that type, using the getter trick.

And I've rewritten `LengthType` so that it's in terms of a generic indexed access, using the *distributive object type* technique as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which makes sure `LengthType<A | B | C>` distributes to `LengthType<A> | LengthType<B> | LengthType<C>`. And now the return value is accepted because `l[length_type]` is of type `LengthTypeValue[T]`, and spreading it into that result gives the intersection from `LengthType<T>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAMqDmAXAFgFQJ4AdgFFzQG8AoKKAZRxhwGFUoBeKAcgqtqYBoTzUBBVAJLUGzMn0HVO3agHkAcgBEBg+SKazFygfKmkACjgBK2hWoPGZCpkQC+RewEsQiYACcAZgEMAxsFgIUDGwANU8AGzA-YlIAbTgQJDQsXHwAOlYaVABdAC4oAigwgOQAZzz8ACM3GKyoGwBubjjioJTIdPEhXPzC4vLIKtc6xtj4xNa8do0lFTlugu8AexAAEwdEB2WyqE8QdBrhprHA5MmIVPMTed6ElAB9CCd+iEH6m8SHzwAPZ8HDuyIiGS-luSWwAB4ANJQYBfFyrEog8anfAAPgY3AKMT0UCcUEh1yKoLuQOweRxNigADIkScQuFItjajYYgTGkR3GAQN4NstcSB1g5wg4AF7AY7IBSeRCecF0WHwlaIiUTNEACiJH1JwDyqAAlHkVck5ejolAliASohCoaWslQhE-IwzaR4MBrc1Qar2hlaFk1Xr8txSKRXO6wK4QD1NShtgc7CG6lxE26PUbsGcLkYrgGg4nQ+HI9Hig8nlAAAwcd73CDfPLlurBpNN1NQT3IjNpMT8Lq5l0hsOICNRgox5D1xuJmzJkOt9t0trnaZaeT+wP9gtDosLZZrXmWvLxpsJydQQfD4vE7VV1K3sIxMck5LMxo2IA)